# Getting lastModified in a webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way to get the last modified date of a file in a webextension? I want to be able to get this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified, but I'm not sure how to get the File object when given a local file path. On the webpage it says that

> In Gecko, privileged code can create File objects representing any local file without user interaction

But I'm not too sure how to go about doing that. I tried `new File("file:///F:/Documents/test.txt");`, but that just gave me the `too few arguments` error, which was expected.

I managed to get the file itself with the fetch command `fetch(filePath, {mode: "same-origin"});`, but the headers only contained the file size and the file type, not `Last-Modified`.

I also tried a `XMLHttpRequest();`, with the permissions `<all_urls>`, but that gave me the error: `Security Error: Content at moz-extension://path/to/extension/page may not load or link to file:///F:/Documents/test.txt.`

Comment: Where did you took this quote from? Didn't it redirected you to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code)? Don't hesitate to follow the links when reading docs/

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but I can't tell how that page applies, I'm not even sure if I am programming in "chrome code" or not, and any googling about chrome code just give me google chrome. When I try to call `File.createFromFileName("path/to/some/file");`, all I get is that createFromFileName doesn't exist. Any pointers?